# Releasing 2 applications based on same code but different package name

Tags: android, command-line, google-play, package, aapt

Like many Android developers I want to have two programs for MarketPlace - a demo and a full version - they both have the same code but use different assets. Unfortunately as they have the same package namespace they cannot both be loaded onto the same device. By the way, the assets are in an asset folder and not in the res folder.

I want to make the second **apk** via the command line and derive it from the first **apk** that was compiled/built using NetBeans/Eclipse IDE.

The answer seemed to be **aapt** and its `--rename-package-manifest` option but I clearly don't understand how to use it.

I do the following steps:

1. Build my full apk using NetBeans
2. Unpack apk with **apktool**
3. Add the new assets
4. Rename the package with **aapt**
5. Repack into demo version using **apktool**.

However, I cannot get step 4 -  the **aapt** rename stage to work. I have seen so many threads on the web about this but no explicit example.

I then tried the very simplest of programs to test it out - an Hello World using following the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html).

The Hello World works fine using command line options, it builds and runs on both emulator and device.

However, when I use the **aapt** `--rename-manifest-package` command it gives lots of errors.

The command I use is:

```
  aapt package -f -v 
         -M c:\android-sdk-windows\tools\hellow\AndroidManifest.xml 
         -S c:\android-sdk-windows\tools\hellow\res
         —rename-package-manifest com.myname.demo
```

The errors are in both the `main.xml` and the `AndroidManifest.xml` are of the form:

> "No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_width'"

Any ideas would be really welcome.

Comment: the option is --rename-manifest-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Android library project, as this was designed with your scenario in mind. Here are instructions for using Android library projects [with Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject) or [without Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html#libraryProject).

Comment: Thank you for this. I had a look and it seems that the library source code must be there so that they can be merged with the main program.

Comment: The article gives an overview of how two versions can be built without the java source code being available - it needs aapt --rename-manifest-package option but I can't get that to work   http://blog.uncommons.org/2010/07/19/building-two-versions-of-the-same-android-app/

Comment: @MacieFranks: "I had a look and it seems that the library source code must be there so that they can be merged with the main program" -- no, although it takes a bit of trickery to create binary-only library projects. See the Binary-Only Library Projects section in http://andparcel.com/articles/parcel